# How do i recreate a html request header?

Tags: java, html

I'm currently writing a Java Application that remotely controls my Roku.  I found [this](http://remoku.tv) website and used it to control my Roku.  From Chromes developer tools i watched its data traffic and found the html request that controlled the Roku.  The Header was this.

```
POST /keydown/Play HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.xxx.x.82:8060
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://remoku.tv
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://remoku.tv/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I then tried to recreate this POST request within Java and it ended up looking like this:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
URL url = new URL("html://192.xxx.x.82:8060/keydown/Play");
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://192.xxx.x.254");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://192.xxx.x.254");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the correct way to recreate the request because it does not have the same effect as the the original (working).  However, this may be because I changed a few minor details that may have actually be important.  So my question to you is if this the correct way to recreate a request and if it is why is it not working?  If not what is?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http compoents frm apache https://hc.apache.org/

Comment: Preferable I would like to use preinstalled libraries and no external jars.

Comment: As far as I know, Java does not have full support for http. But can see  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tgkprog's comment i edited my code to this:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
URL url = new URL("http://192.xxx.x.82:8060/keypress/Right");
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream())) {
             wr.writeChars("");
}

System.out.println(urlConn.getResponseCode());
```

and now it works perfectly and I can control my Roku the problem was i was not using the correct keys in the header as they where not in caps lock in Chrome (edit: they are not needed).

Comment: You're just sending a POST request for a button press. There's probably many of those headers that aren't really necessary

Comment: Probably but i'm new to HTTP and have no idea what is needed  so better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: You just need to get the request to the roku, so for example, it probably doesn't care what your user agent is or what the cache control is set to